# Trying to read from a binary file to an array

Tags: java, arrays, binaryfiles

I'm working on a school assignment, the requirements are as follows: "Design a class that has a static method named writeArray.  The method should take two arguments: the name of the file and a reference to an int array.  The file should be opened as a binary file, the contents of the array should be written to the file, then the file should be closed.  Write a second method in the class named readArray.  The method should take two arguments: the name of a file, and a reference to an int array.  The file should be opened, data should be read from the file and stored in the array, then the file should be closed.  Demonstrate both methods in a program."

Here's my code so far for the class and demo:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileArray

{
    
public static void writeArray(String filename, int[] array) throws IOException
{
    //Open the file.

    DataOutputStream outputFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("MyNumbers.txt"));
    
    //Write the array.
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        outputFile.writeInt(array[index]);
    }
    
    //Close the file.
    outputFile.close();
}

public static void readArray(String filename, int[] array) throws IOException
{
    int number;
    boolean endOfFile = false;
    
    //Open the file.
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("MyNumbers.txt");
    DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    
    //Read values from the array.
    while (!endOfFile)
    {
        try
        {
            number = inputFile.readInt();
        }
        catch (EOFException e)
        {
            endOfFile = true;
        }
    }
    
    //Close the file.
    inputFile.close();
}
}
```

Second class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileArrayDemo extends FileArray

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        //Create arrays.
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        int[] test = new int[8];
        
        //Try/catch clause.
        try
        {
            //Write the contents of the numbers array to the file MyNumbers.txt.
            FileArray fileArray = new FileArray();
            fileArray.writeArray("MyNumbers.txt", numbers);
            
            //Read the contents of the file MyNumbers.txt into the test array.
            fileArray.readArray("MyNumbers.txt", test);
            
            //Display the numbers from the test array.
            System.out.println("The numbers read from the file are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
            System.out.print(test[i] + " ");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error = " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use the demo file, my array is showing all 0's instead of numbers 1-8.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here at all.  I've been following along with the examples from my book, but they only provide demonstrations in one class instead of having a class that creates methods to perform the write/read operations.

Comment: You're not reading into the array: you're repeatedly reading into a single  `ìnt` variable. Try it again

Comment: Thank you!  I'm quite new here (clearly), I really appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

You need just to modify the array passed in parameters, your `readArray` function is just read and does not modify the array.

try ramplacing your `readArray` function by this one:

```
    public static void readArray(String filename, int[] array) throws IOException{
        int number;
        boolean endOfFile = false;

        //Open the file.
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("MyNumbers.txt");
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(fstream);

        //Read values from the array.
        int i = 0;
        while (!endOfFile){
            try{
                number = inputFile.readInt();
                array[i] = number;
                i++;
                
            }catch (EOFException e)
            {
                endOfFile = true;
            }
        }

        //Close the file.
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

result :

```
The numbers read from the file are:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```